# removing white space from file java

Tags: java, file, whitespace, removing-whitespace

I am trying to work on texts by first removing the stopwords and apply a stemming algorithm on them and finally split them into words  and save them into files.
I did all that and the problem I have is white spaces in the file containing the words as follow:

```
Hi
teacher

mother
sister
father .... and so on
```

The problem is the space between teacher and mother.
I want to remove it. I cant figure out the reason for it.

Here is  a potion of the related code.

```
public void parseFiles(String filePath) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    File[] allfiles = new File(filePath).listFiles();
    BufferedReader in = null;
    for (File f : allfiles) {
        if (f.getName().endsWith(".txt")) {
            fileNameList.add(f.getName());
            Reader fstream = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(f),"UTF-8"); 
            in = new BufferedReader(fstream);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String s=null;
            String word = null;
            while ((s = in.readLine()) != null) {
                s=s.trim().replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9]", " ");        //remove all punctuation for English text
                Scanner input = new Scanner(s);
                  while(input.hasNext()) {              
                       word= input.next();
                       word=word.trim().toLowerCase();
                if(stopword.isStopword(word)==true)
                {
                    word= word.replace(word, "");
                }
                String stemmed=stem.stem (word);
                sb.append(stemmed+"\t");

                  }
                   //System.out.print(sb);

            }
            String[] tokenizedTerms = sb.toString().replaceAll("[\\W&&[^\\s]]", "").split("\\W+");   //to get individual terms  (English)

          for (String term : tokenizedTerms) {
               if (!allTerms.contains(term)) {  //avoid duplicate entry
                 allTerms.add(term);
                   System.out.print(term+"\t");
                 }
            }
            termsDocsArray.add(tokenizedTerms);
        }
    } 
    //System.out.print("file names="+fileNameList);
}
```

Please help.
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not use an if to check if the line is empty?

```
while ((s = in.readLine()) != null) {
  if (!s.trim().isEmpty()) {
  ...
  }
}
```

Comment: I would also add a `trim()`, as you can consider a string empty if it is only made of white spaces

Comment: u can also use `isEmpty()` method

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this for eliminating all empty lines:

```
String yourText = "teacher\nmother etc..";
String adjustedText = yourText.replaceAll("(?m)^[ \t]*\r?\n", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

In your while loop add this condition too,

while ((s = in.readLine()) != null && (!(StringUtils.isBlank(s)))) {

// your logic here.
}